# Access: Display hidden combobox column in textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a combobox with a record source that brings 4 columns, but only shows the second column (`Column Widths: 0";1";0";0"`). I am trying to display the third column value selected in a text box, using the it's control Source property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combo's `Column` property uses zero-based index numbers, so the third column is `Column(2)`.

Set the text box's Control Source property to ...

```vb
=[YourComboName].[Column](2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to show both column 2 and column 3

```
Column Count = 2
Column Width = 0;1;1;0
```

If you're looking to show column 3 instead of column 2

```
Column Width = 0;0;1;0
```