# selected record to text boxes MS access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have table named "Student" in sub form in Access. I also have text boxes with ID and Name, when I select a name from list it's corresponding ID and Name should be populated in text boxes.

```
ID  name
34  ABC
53  XYZ
67  ZEN
86  PEC
12  REC
34  DEB
```

Comment: Please share your own attempt, and any errors you encounter. Currently, this question is too broad in my opinion, since we can't answer it without details on your exact setup.

Comment: Textbox ControlSource property can reference columns of combobox by index. Index begins with 0 so column 1 is index 0 `=[comboboxname].Column(0)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access: Display hidden combobox column in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084768/access-display-hidden-combobox-column-in-textbox)